# Problem with basic Android xml GUI

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

I've just started working on a basic Android GUI using XML - when I run it, logcat tells me `"Binary XML file line #16: You must supply a layout_width attribute."`

When I try and the program, it throws the error "The application HelloAndroid has stopped unexpectedly.

Its the basic hello Android code - 
   UPDATE - Got it so far! Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Yes, the landscape version is relevant. Android automatically selects the appropriate layout for the device orientation - you don't have to set it manually. Also this layout seems to be correct, so please post the landscape version.

Comment: Think I found it because of the text highlighting already! A lot easier to see my error now other people are scrutinising my code!

Answer (score 1):

There is a part in your layout:

```
<TextView  
    android:text="@string/main_title"/> 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    android:marginBuottom="20dip"
    android:textSize="24.5sp" />
```

As you can already see from the code highlighting here, some parts of this element are black. Thats because you closed this `TextView` via `/>` on the second line. All the other parameters are not belonging to this element anymore. Therefore the parser can't find `layout_width`, `layout_height` and so on - and complains about this ("you didnt specify ..."). Remove the `/>` on the top and you should be fine.

**Edit:** The correct version should look like this:

```
<TextView  
    android:text="@string/main_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:marginBottom="20dip"
    android:textSize="24.5sp" />
```

or alternatively (since this here is the shorthand version

```
<TextView  
    android:text="@string/main_title" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:marginBottom="20dip"
    android:textSize="24.5sp"> </TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This view looks OK. But check your landscape xml. There's an issue with `layout_width` property in the xml - it's missing or maybe there's some typing mistakes (usually `android:layout_width` replaced with `android.layout_width`).

`android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` properties are required for every control you add to the xml.

**EDIT:**

```
<TextView  
                    android:text="@string/main_title"/> 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                    android:marginBuottom="20dip"
                    android:textSize="24.5sp" />
```

You are ending your TextView element after the android:text property - `android:text="@string/main_title"/>`. Remove `/>`

**EDIT:**

Also you have an typing mistake in `android:marginBuottom="20dip"`. This line should be a `android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"`.